# Running Jupiter Lab via Command Line WIndows

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have followed the instruction on the [official website](https://jupyter.org/install) of Jupyter.

I installed JupyterLab with pip:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

And then I tried to run JupyterLab with:

```
jupyter-lab
```

It says the following error:

```
'jupyter-lab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I checked the Environment Variables (I use Windows 10) and I am pretty sure that it's correct.

I tried to use the following command:

```
python -m notebook
```

but is says this:

```
C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\python.exe: No module named notebook
```

Why does it use the path for Inkspace (it's another program) to run python? And why is python installed in this folder?

Comment: Can you find `jupyter-lab` on your computer? (Use `dir C:jupyter-lab.exe /s`) If so, is it included in the PATH? What do you get if you use `where python` command?

Comment: `C:\Users\<ucsername>\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts` is the directory

and `%PY_HOME%;%PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk;`

is in the path

Comment: Try to add this directory `...\Scripts` to the PATH. I use miniconda (and installed jupyter by miniconda) without any problem.

Comment: py -m pip install notebook

Answer (score 1):

For Windows run this command in PowerShell

```
python -m jupyterlab
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```bash
jupyter lab
```

or

```bash
python -m jupyter lab
```

For jupyter notebook run `jupyter notebook` or `python -m jupyter notebook`

Install jupyter notebook before running `jupyter notebook` by running `pip install jupyter notebook`